# Does heavy water taste sweet?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water, taste

In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXHVqId0MQc) from Cody's Lab, Cody claims that heavy water tastes sweet.

He does some fairly convincing comparisons but still expresses a little doubt that the effect is real.

Has this been studied by others? Is the effect verified and if so, what possible explanations exist?

Comment: Just as a side note: You might find the *vibrational theory of olfaction* interesting, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibration_theory_of_olfaction

Comment: dude dont try anything of that sort! I just saw that guy drinking cyanide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWNpO5vvhpk

Comment: @Tetrahydrocannabinol he also took a bite out of sodium metal...

Comment: I find cold water sweeter than warm water and he did say that heavy water feels colder.

Comment: @Tetrahydrocannabinol - I found Cody's youtube channel a while back, when he was embedding magnets in his fingers.  He's certainly ... *interesting*.  But I don't think most people would be advised to do many of the things he does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the abstract of the article by Abu et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.05.22.110205)]:

> Here we conclusively demonstrate that humans are, nevertheless, able to distinguish $\ce{D2O}$ from $\ce{H2O}$ by taste. Indeed, highly purified heavy water has a distinctly sweeter taste than same-purity normal water and adds to perceived sweetness of sweeteners. In contrast, mice do not prefer $\ce{D2O}$ over $\ce{H2O},$ indicating that they are not likely to perceive heavy water as sweet. For humans, the sweet taste of $\ce{D2O}$ is suppressed by lactisole, which is a known sweetness inhibitor acting via the TAS1R3 monomer of the TAS1R2/TAS1R3 sweet taste receptor. HEK 293T cells transfected with the TAS1R2/TAS1R3 heterodimer and the chimeric Gα16gust44 G-protein are activated by $\ce{D2O}$ but not by $\ce{H2O}$. The present study resolves a long-standing controversy about the taste of heavy water, confirms that its sweet taste is mediated by the human TAS1R2/TAS1R3 taste receptor, and opens way to future studies of potential sites and modes of action.

#### Reference

1. Abu, N. B.; Mason, P. E.; Klein, H.; Dubovski, N.; Shoshan-Galeczki, Y. B.; Malach, E.; Pražienková, V.; Maletínská, L.; Tempra, C.; Chamorro, V. C.; Cvačka, J.; Behrens, M.; Niv, M. Y.; Jungwirth, P. Sweet Taste of Heavy Water. *bioRxiv* **2020**, 2020.05.22.110205. DOI: [10.1101/2020.05.22.110205](https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.05.22.110205)

Answer (score 42):

According to H.C. Urey and G. Failla, [Science  15 Mar 1935,
Vol. 81, Issue 2098, pp. 273](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/81/2098/273.2), there's no difference in the taste of ordinary and heavy water.

Comment: Very small sample size but an interesting reference indeed! (+1)

Comment: And now one definitively shown to be wrong by the Abu, et. al. paper.

Answer (score 34):

OK, first of all I want to say I really dislike the videos that this guy puts out, since he is promoting unsafe handling of chemicals. He might know what he's doing, but it's a terrible example.

To the actual question: surprisingly there are nearly no sources on this. I can understand that this isn't something a lot of people would try nowadays, but I imagined that a lot of people tried 50 years ago or something like that.

There's [one science article](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/81/2098/273.2) describing a blind taste test of three persons in comparison to distilled water, and they couldn't spot a difference.

[Another paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031938479901240) describes a difference, and also cites older research that showed that rats avoid $\ce{D2O}$ if they have the option to choose. But that might also be smell. It is known that deuterated substances can have a different smell and taste.

Heavy water also has a higher density and viscosity, so that might also be a factor which makes it "taste" different. Fun fact: it also has a different color.

And well, he didn't do the testing in a scientific manner, which would minimally include blinding the observer.

Comment: Watch the video starting at 6:47. He let his girlfriend (or his sister, or someone, idk) taste taste taste it and she didn't know which tube contained normal water and which one contained heavy water.

Comment: @UTF-8 The odds of it being sheer luck is 50%. No conclusions can be drawn from that.

Comment: _"he is promoting unsafe handling of chemicals"_ - ..and explosives. I hope he doesn't learn the hard way what static electricity can do to an unstable explosive.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Well, my sister started studying biology.They had a group visit a lecture.That group tested some gene manipulation on mice. They had 8 mice in total so I guess probably at most 4 which got a treatment. My sister has no idea what's meant by some number and then "sigma" but the group said that everything equal to or above 0.5 σ is relevant for confirming their hypotheses. So if you compare it with what's called "science" in biology ... :D ;-) Of course it's just 2 people on YT allegedly tasting it. But a study involving 3 people stating the opposite isn't exactly meaningful either.

Comment: @UTF-8 - I watched that video recently and IIRC the test tube that purported to be heavy water was marked with a sticker. Less than subtle choice forcing in my opinion.

Comment: @oPless Some way of reliably telling them apart is needed. He could've attached the sticker to either one.

Comment: Maybe his videos are promoting dangerous behaviour. Or, since **he** seems to take good precautions, they are bait for the Darwin awards.

Comment: @matt_black Maybe? Really? He is biting into sodium metal. There's also no good precautions you can take for that. It's just dangerous and extremly stupid.

Comment: It's educational, though. Extremely stupid is being reckless for [no apparent gain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOx-z5YS1aE).

Comment: @CeesTimmerman what's the educational value of biting into sodium? And I doubt it's for education, it's more likely just for money, and doing dangerous stuff for a little bit of money is stupid in my eyes. There are so many interesting and educational experiments you could do instead of eating cyanide or biting into sodium (but you will make less money).

Comment: [He explains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj6vn8LlA04) why biting sodium sounds like a terrible idea, and why his attempt is likely to succeed while warning people not to replicate it. He doesn't mess around doing the same stunt until it kills him and/or others. Was sodium metal generally known to taste tangy and turn tongue tips into soap before? I think not.

Answer (score 3):

I tastet heavy water assuming it has not taste and was surprised about the sweet taste (Aldrich, Deuterium oxide, 99.9%). The bottle was old but still sealed. Three more people also defined the content of the same bottle as slightly sweet without knowing what my perception was.

Comment: Please expand on your answer - the OP asks, in addition to if this effect has been studied (not observed) and verified by others, what possible explanations exist.